# symfony2 forms from entity

Tags: forms, symfony

Okay, so I'm using symfony2 and I'm trying to create an option box in this form based off another Entity...

So in my controller I have:

```
<?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Controller\Report;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Report\TimeClockReportType;

class TimeClockReportController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $start = null;
        $end = null;
        $dateRangeForm = $this->createForm(new TimeClockReportType());

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $dateRangeForm->bindRequest($request);
            $formData = $dateRangeForm->getData();

            $start = $formData['dateRange']['startDate'];
            $end = $formData['dateRange']['endDate'];
        }

        return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:Reports:TimeClockReport.html.twig', array(
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end,
            'form' => $dateRangeForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

and my TimeClockReportType.php looks like:

```
    <?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Report;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

use Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts\DateRangeType;
use Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts\DepartmentSelectionType;


class TimeClockReportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dateRange', new DateRangeType())
            ->add('salesCompany', new DepartmentSelectionType(true));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ecs_crmbundle_TimeClockReportType';
    }

}
```

and my DepartmentSelectionType looks like:

```
    <?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\Parts;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class DepartmentSelectionType extends AbstractType
{
    private $canSeeAll = false;

    public function __construct($canSeeAll = false)
    {
        $this->canSeeAll = $canSeeAll;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('department', 'entity',
                array(
                    'class' => "EcsAgentManagerBundle:EmployeeDepartment",
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => "Department"))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\EmployeeDepartment',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ecs_crmbundle_departmentselectiontype';
    }
}
```

The problem that i'm coming up with, is i'm getting just a blank white screen...  But, if i remove the:

`->add('salesCompany', new DepartmentSelectionType(true))` from the `TimeClockReportType` it works just fine...  But I can't see any errors or why it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

A blank page indicates a parse error / engine error has occurred.  I would suggest altering your php.ini file to have display_errors on.

Be sure to restart your webserver after.